# Why does the prototype of `printf` have `restrict`?

Tags: c, printf, restrict-qualifier

The prototype of `printf`, according to my `stdio.h`, is

```
extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

On the page explaining [Restrict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict), it says that it is a keyword used to indicate that pointers are unique. However, I don't understand why one would need that for `printf`.

**Why does `printf` have a "restrict" keyword?**

If it's necessary to explain further what "restrict" means, please do.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the format string shouldn't overlap with any of its arguments or the results are undefined. The `restrict` makes that clear beyond just mentioning it the documentation.

As for why...

In the case of `snprintf()` and `sprintf()` it should be obvious why the format shouldn't overlap with especially the destination buffer, but it's a bit murkier for the variations that output to a file.

I *suspect* it's because of the `%hhn` specifier, which sets its argument, a `signed char *`, to the number of characters written so far. If you pass a pointer to an element of the format string, this would modify the string and thus possibly introduce undefined behavior - what if the number corresponds to the value of the character `'%'`?

Comment: Maybe post this answer on the duplicate, which only has wrong answers right now...

Comment: @R.. Huh, must have posted this at the same time it was closed. I'll think about it.